# Oracle 11g: LISTAGG ignores NULL values

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have some table `TABLE1` with data:

```
+------------+
|    COL1    |
+------------+
|   FOO      |
|   BAR      |
|  (null)    |
|   EXP      |
+------------+
```

(  [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44d37/3/0) )

When I executing:

```
SELECT listagg(col1, '#') within group(ORDER BY rownum) 
  FROM table1
```

I receive: `FOO#BAR#EXP` but I want to have: `FOO#BAR##EXP`

(`LISTAGG` ignoring empty cells :/ )

Any idea to achieve that without writing own function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select replace(listagg(NVL(col1, '#'), '#') 
within group(order by rownum),'###','##') from table1
```

you can use the `NVL(col1, '#')`  here you can pass any value instead of null.

[**HErE is the demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44d37/62)

Comment: This is not working when two consecutive columns are NULL, as REPLACE will only replace the first occurrence and it unable to match the following one. Any hint on this?

Answer (score 8):

```
select substr(listagg('#'||col1) within group (order by rownum),2)
from table1
```

Prepend the separator before each value (this yields the separator only for NULLs), then aggregate without separator, and strip the leading separator.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
select replace(
                listagg(coalesce(col1,'replace'), '#') 
                within group(order by rownum),      
       'replace','') 
from table1
```

**Sql Fiddle [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44d37/39/0)**

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select replace(listagg(nvl(col1, '#') , '#') 
       within group(order by rownum), '##', '#') 
from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using [model clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2172805).

```
SQL> select rtrim(res, '#') as col1
  2    from ( select res
  3                , rn
  4             from table1
  5             model
  6             dimension by (rownum as rn)
  7             measures(cast(null as varchar2(500)) as res, col1)
  8             rules(
  9               res[any] order by rn desc= col1[cv()] || '#' || res[cv() + 1]
 10             )
 11          )
 12   where rn = 1
 13  /

COL1
--------------------
FOO#BAR##EXP
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/083f0/18)

Comment: @WBAR More information on [model clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2172805)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
  REPLACE(listagg(NVL(col1,' '), '#') within group(order by rownum),'# #','##') 
from table1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44d37/29)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO its worth mentioning that with using `listagg`, you will likely encounter limit of the 4000 chars on result value and then seek some alternative solution. The solution is `xmlagg`, which by contrast *respects* `null` values. Hence consider whether using placeholder-based tricks with `listagg` is worth.

(My case was the opposite: I needed to *ignore* nulls which perfectly fits `listagg` but then I reached the limit and was forced to learn ignoring values with `xmlagg` clause. Which is possible using `nvl2` function but that's another story.)